# Import swagger-codegen project into existing Android project

Tags: android-studio, android-volley, build.gradle, okhttp, swagger-codegen

Im trying to integrate a "module"-project generated by swagger-codegen, into my Android project.

Haven't worked that much with gradle before and the swagger-codegen creates a quite messy build.gradle from my point of view.

I have a hard time finding documentation on how to do this. And I feel a bit lost.

I used this method described in the [FAQ](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/FAQ#android)

```
mvn clean package
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate \
 -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json \
 -l java --library=okhttp-gson \
 -o /var/tmp/java/okhttp-gson/
```

So fare I tried to copy the source from the project that was generated by swagger-codegen and merge the two gradle build files. I removed the Junit tests because I couldn't get the Junit dependency working ([Implementing Swagger-codegen project - Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638467/implementing-swagger-codegen-project-error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitj/38648612?noredirect=1#comment64732498_38648612)). But then I got stuck with some conflict between the plugins?

```
The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.
```

Here's the build.gradle:

```
import static jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.regexp.joni.ApplyCaseFold.apply

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

group = 'io.swagger'
version = '1.0.0'

buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
       // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.+'
       classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
   }
}

repositories {
   jcenter()
   maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}


if(hasProperty('target') && target == 'android') {

   apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
   apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
       defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
       }
        compileOptions {
           sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
           targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
       }

       // Rename the aar correctly
       libraryVariants.all { variant ->
           variant.outputs.each { output ->
               def outputFile = output.outputFile
               if (outputFile != null &&    outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
                    def fileName = "\u0024{project.name}-  \u0024{variant.baseName}-\u0024{version}.aar"
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        def task = project.tasks.create "jar${variant.name.capitalize()}", Jar
        task.description = "Create jar artifact for ${variant.name}"
        task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
        task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
        task.destinationDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/jar")
        task.archiveName = "${project.name}-${variant.baseName}-${version}.jar"
        artifacts.add('archives', task);
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

} else {

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.artifactId = 'XxxxXxxx'
    }
}

    task execute(type:JavaExec) {
       main = System.getProperty('mainClass')
       classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3'
   // testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Am I doing something complete wrong here? What is the correct way to implement swagger-codegen code into my project?

Answer (score 3):

The swift way to import it was to compile the swagger generated project then copy the .jar file to my android project and add its as a library.

Comment: Generating the .jar (and importing later) file after opening the Swagger project worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I have a hard time finding documentation on how to do this. And I feel a bit lost.

You could clone the [Android swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/android/volley/build.gradle) example.

(which does use Junit, so I'm not sure what error you got)

Unless that's what you mean by

> So far I tried to copy the source and merge the two gradle build files

To which, I ask, what two Gradle files? It looks like you merged an Android Gradle file with a Java Gradle file, which seems to causing more issues because you are getting...

> The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.

Which seems pretty self explanatory when you have this line

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

It's not too clear what you are trying to do here other than check the build target

```
if(hasProperty('target') && target == 'android')
```

Comment: Thanks for the great hints! I clarified the question a bit about what I meant by the source. But I shall take a look at the example source.

Comment: The two build gradle files I mean is the one that is found in the project that swagger-codegen generated and the one that is in the original Android project

Comment: I see. I looks like you generated a Java one, though, not an Android one

Comment: Maybe I generated the code wrong In some way? Maybe that's why it wan'ts to use apply plugin:  'java'?

Comment: I would agree with you, but I'd need to read into Swagger-codegen more to give a definite answer

Comment: Yeah that's probably it!

Comment: In the FAQ it says "The Java SDK is also compatible with Android." and they recommend to generatet it with "-l java".